# AppArmor causing mysql to stop?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, apparmor

We have two Ubuntu instances both having MySQL server. MySQL in one gets shutdown everyday almost without any apparent reason. 
`Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1031-aws x86_64)`

Only thing I could found in the instance where MySQL gets stopped is `AppArmor`. Initially I though it should not create any issue to MySQL. But to be on safe side I tried to delete the apparmor.

Here is the log for app armor delete

```
ubuntu@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XX:~$ sudo apt remove apparmor
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-XX-XXX-XX-XX: Resource temporarily unavailable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1021 linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1023 linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1027 linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1029 linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1032
  linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1033
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apparmor snapd ubuntu-core-launcher
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 139 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 69.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 222315 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-core-launcher (2.37.4+18.04.1) ...
Removing snapd (2.37.4+18.04.1) ...
Removing apparmor (2.12-4ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf because link group my.cnf is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /etc/mysql/my.cnf with a link
Checking if update is needed.
Checking server version.
Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 1146: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 5
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Why does AppArmor try to upgrade MySQL, even while trying to uninstall?

Can it be the reason for MySQL to shutdown ? (Everyday ~ 6:30 AM UTC)

*EDIT*
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127264/cant-start-mysql-mysql-respawning-too-fast-stopped/129143#129143) answer may help it looks like. But question remains, why does apparmor need to update mysql even when trying to uninstall?
If I change the variables from

`default-character-set = utf8`
to
`character_set_server  = utf8`

I may work, but does that mean, app armor will automatically update/upgrade the mysql?

P.S.
There is a similar type of question but it has very few detail and does not have answer. Didn't try to delete app armor, so I am putting question separate.

Comment: The answer to the link implies a configuration problem with MySQL _after_ it is installed.  (So I don't think it is relevant.)

Comment: Try posting on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your mysql/system logs?

Comment: No relevant messages in mysql logs.

Comment: The link is related to this problem I understand but the question is why does app armor is trying to update!. If I change the parameters as suggested in the other answer, it will successfully upgrade - not that is another issue - I don't want it to be upgraded without any testing.

Answer (score 0):

first run **sudo apt autoremove** and see it will help another issue I can see is **sudo: unable to resolve host ip-XX-XXX-XX-XX: Resource temporarily unavailable** try to fix these and retry. I think some stale config or resources forcing mysql changes beware if it is production and check what it is removing before accepting changes.